# cte always produces issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I try to create cte but I feel like I've always having trouble while executing it. I double checked my code and everything looks right to me. While I was running the script inside the cte alone, it works fine. But when I put it in a cte, it says "incorrect syntax near ')'"

Does anyone know why this keeps happening? All my () should work fine. Please help!

Script:

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    select a.custid,count(a.orderid),rank() over (order by count(a.orderid) desc) as 'num'
    from sales.orders a
    group by a.custid
    )
select * from cte
```

Comment: try this `;WITH...` also alias your count column

Comment: What RDBMS is this running under?  I'm surprised `AS 'num'` is allowed, because `'num'` is a string literal, not a column name/identifier.  You probably meant `"num"` or just `num` instead.

Comment: this is for MSSQL, I tried "num" and added ; ,  it still gives me the error stating -- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding ";" semicolon in front of WITH?

```
;WITH cte AS
    (
    select a.custid,count(a.orderid) AS OrderCount,rank() over (order by count(a.orderid) desc) as 'num'
    from sales.orders a
    group by a.custid
    )
select * from cte
```

Comment: yes, and it is saying -- Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 39
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'cte'.